# Use stack memory as heap memory without UB

Tags: rust, stack, heap-memory, allocator

I am working in an environment where I cannot use heap memory but only stack memory. To not be constrained by the `#[no_std]` enviroment I tried to use stack memory as heap memory with the [linked-list-allocator](https://crates.io/crates/linked_list_allocator) crate. This was my approach.

```rust
use linked_list_allocator::LockedHeap;
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOCATOR: LockedHeap = LockedHeap::empty();

pub unsafe fn init_heap(heap_start: usize, heap_size: usize) {
    ALLOCATOR.lock().init(heap_start, heap_size);
}

fn main() {
    const HEAP_SIZE: usize = 2048;
    let mut heap: MaybeUninit<[u8; HEAP_SIZE]> = MaybeUninit::zeroed();
    unsafe { init_heap(heap.as_mut_ptr() as usize, HEAP_SIZE) }
    println!(
        "{} {} {} {} {} {}",
        "This", "String", "Has", "Been", "Dynamically", "Allocated"
    );
}
```

Compiling and running the following code on my laptop with an `llvm-target` of `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` and a `rustc` version `1.49.0-nightly` I get the following error:

```
memory allocation of 4 bytes failedAborted (core dumped)
```

Is there some rust compiler's assumptions that I am infringing or is my usage of the [linked-list-allocator](https://crates.io/crates/linked_list_allocator) wrong?

Edit:
Given the answer and comments from [Masklinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8182118/masklinn) here is a working example:

```
#![feature(start)]

use linked_list_allocator::LockedHeap;

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOCATOR: LockedHeap = LockedHeap::empty();

pub unsafe fn init_heap(heap_start: usize, heap_size: usize) {
    ALLOCATOR.lock().init(heap_start, heap_size);
}

#[start]
fn main(_argn: isize, _argv: *const *const u8) -> isize {
    const HEAP_SIZE: usize = 2048;
    let mut heap = [0u8; HEAP_SIZE];
    unsafe { init_heap(heap.as_mut_ptr() as usize, HEAP_SIZE) }
    std::mem::forget(heap);

    println!(
        "{} {} {} {} {} {}",
        "This", "String", "Has", "Been", "Dynamically", "Allocated"
    );
    0
}
```

Comment: Can't really help with linked-list-allocator, you but your use of `MaybeUninit` seems unnecessary: why not just use a regular array since you're zeroing it either way?

Comment: Thinking about it a bit, I'm guessing the issue could be that the default entry point performs heap allocations before it even calls `main` (`main` is not the actual entry point of the binary).

Comment: @Masklinn it was mainly to prevent any possible optimization that the compiler might do on `heap`. But replacing the two lines of code with:

`let mut heap = [0u8; HEAP_SIZE]; unsafe { init_heap((&mut heap[0]) as *mut u8 as usize, HEAP_SIZE) }
`
yields the same result on my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into the code and finding what looks a lot like the default entry point I'll put what I think is the confirmation of my guess as an answer: the `global_allocator` *must* be fully initialised before `main`, because the default entry point relies on it and allocates: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/std/src/rt.rs#L40-L45

```rust
        // Next, set up the current Thread with the guard information we just
        // created. Note that this isn't necessary in general for new threads,
        // but we just do this to name the main thread and to give it correct
        // info about the stack bounds.
        let thread = Thread::new(Some("main".to_owned()));
        thread_info::set(main_guard, thread);
```

I first missed it and looked into `sys::args::init` but it doesn't seem to allocate (until you request `std::args::args`), but as it turns out there's an obvious allocation right there, of the `main`. And there's actually a second allocation in `Thread::new` (it creates an `Arc`).

So you will have to `no_std`, and probably use `alloc` directly or something. The "embedded" forums / discuss / ... may be more helpful there as that's really not something I ever touched.

Comment: Indeed. Using `LockedHeap` as a local variable instead of as the global allocator seems to work fine.